# select Case with subqueries select and using Top

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi  i  want to retrive the list of browsers  used by user id

Table Contains

> UserID int
>
> BrowserName   nvarchar(40)

here is my Query

```
select browser =
CASE
    WHEN ( PATINDEX('%IE%',BrowserName) IS not null)  THEN   SUBSTRING(BrowserName,PatIndex('%IE%',BrowserName),8) 
   WHEN (PATINDEX('%Firefox%',BrowserName) IS not null)  THEN SUBSTRING(BrowserName,PatIndex('%Firefox%',BrowserName),8)
   WHEN (PATINDEX('%Chrome%',BrowserName) IS not null)  THEN SUBSTRING(BrowserName,PatIndex('%Chrome%',BrowserName),6)
END



from tableBrowsers where UserId =21
```

But how to select only top 1 substring in this query .

eg : after when in case statement i n need only one row returned for that case,   i tried this, but not getting idea how to implement in case

```
THEN   select top 1 SUBSTRING(BrowserName,PatIndex('%IE%',BrowserName),8)  from browsertable
```

output will be like this

IE

FIREFOX

CHROME

if the user used three browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT browser = 
CASE 
    WHEN ( PATINDEX('%IE%',BrowserName) IS not null)  THEN   SUBSTRING(BrowserName,PatIndex('%IE%',BrowserName),8)  
   WHEN (PATINDEX('%Firefox%',BrowserName) IS not null)  THEN SUBSTRING(BrowserName,PatIndex('%Firefox%',BrowserName),8) 
   WHEN (PATINDEX('%Chrome%',BrowserName) IS not null)  THEN SUBSTRING(BrowserName,PatIndex('%Chrome%',BrowserName),6) 
END 
FROM tableBrowsers where UserId =21
```

Comment: Other than Distinct ? is there any possibility ??? ? though it serves my need, but distinct will take more load ?? ??

Comment: I don't see any other way (except maybe GROUP BY but that would make the query more complex and effectively be the same). For improving performance, you may want to store the computed substring value in a separate column (e.g. using a trigger)